# Why does mkdir() followed by ofstream::operator<< fail with permission denied?

Tags: c++, linux, mkdir, ofstream

The following supposed-to-be-simple program fails with `errno 13: Permission denied`. There's something about file/directory permissions I'm not seeing or understanding; can anyone help identify the problem?

**Preface**

```
>whoami
usera
>cd ~
>mkdir abc
>ls -ld abc
drwxrwxr-x 2 usera usera 4096 May  2 16:36 abc
>cd abc
```

**Code (in the current, i.e. "abc" directory)**

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  const std::string path = "./foo/";
  int result = 0;
  errno = 0;

  result = mkdir( path.c_str(), 0666 );
  std::cout << result << ": " << errno << ": " << strerror( errno ) << std::endl;
  std::string tmp = path + "fooFile";
  std::ofstream ofs( tmp.c_str(), std::ofstream::out );
  ofs << "hello, world!";
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << ofs.good() << std::endl;
  ofs.close();
  std::cout << result << ": " << errno << ": " << strerror( errno ) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Execution**

```
>ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 usera usera 585 May  2 16:39 main.cpp

>g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

>g++ -g main.cpp && ./a.out
0: 0: Success
false
0: 13: Permission denied
>
>ls -l
total 52
-rwxrwxr-x 1 usera usera 41844 May  2 16:44 a.out
drw-rw-r-- 2 usera usera  4096 May  2 16:44 foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 usera usera   585 May  2 16:39 main.cpp
```

The error is telling me *something* RE: file/directory permissions is wrong, but I can't see what. From the `ls` output, it looks to me that all files are owned by me, so I'm unclear why a permission denied error should occur. Please enlighten me what's wrong here.

Comment: Can you check the return on `mkdir`? It should be 0 if successful (and if not you should use `strerror` right there before even trying to open a file).

Comment: @scohe001 - Updated code per your suggestion: `mkdir()` shows success.

Comment: You need to run your program with a "super user" privilege.

Comment: @raindrop7 “Permission denied” doesn’t always mean you’re missing a `sudo`

Comment: `mkdir()` did *not* fail.

Comment: You should not use sudo indiscriminately. Most likely there is a way to accomplish what you want without sudo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [need execution permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21263) to access the contents of a directory. Change your permission argument to something like 0755.

If you have read without execute, you can enumerate the elements of a directory but you can't access them. Write without execute is meaningless on directories.